# Perimeter question

Tags: geometry

ABCD is a rectangle and CEFG is a square.
Given HK = 5 cm and perimeter of shaded region is 30 cm.
Find the length of the sides of CEFG.

Have been stuck for days. Appreciate any help. Thank you vm

[image: Link to diagram]

Comment: `Given HK = 5 cm` That's redundant.

Comment: Hint: let $x$ be the length of the sides of $CEFG$. Then the perimeter of the shaded area is $30 = 5 + 6 + 2 + x + x + ED + DK$. Express $ED$ and $DK$ in terms of $x$. Replace and solve for $x$.

Comment: $$P(HBGFEDK)=P(ABCD)+HK-AH-AK$$ And $CG$ can be written in terms of $P(ABCD)$ and constants.

Comment: @dxiv Got me unstuck! Thank-you, that helps. Care to add as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$30=EF+FG+GB+BH+HK+KD+DE$
$30=x+x+2+6+5+((2+x)-4)+(9-x)$

Just solve for $x$